# Image sprites and touch devices

Tags: html, css, sprite

I've been searching for hours on a solution for this. The issue doesn't arise on the desktop however I had seen it on occasion with unpredictability in IE9 & FF4. essentially I am using a single massive image sprite and using it through my stylesheet. For some reason, any element with a shadow shows a gap or break below it. I've left plenty of space beneath this particular section to not be running into another section of the image.

I've tried adjusting the height of the areas and that didn't seem to matter. The line gap/border still appear under the header and under the shadow of the content area.

Also noticed this occurs when zoomed in at various levels in Safari.

Please see http://www.kintera.org/site/lookup.asp?c=dlKQK4NOJiI8F

Comment: On what kind of device does this happen?

Comment: I only have tha ability to test the iPhone.

Comment: The page looks fine on my Android phone (also a mobile WebKit browser), which suggests that the problem is related specifically to Safari's scaling. Have you checked desktop Safari's zoom / magnify function to see if it does the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sprite has a gap or a line removed. Looks as though this could be potentially causing the problem:

[image]

Since the background colour of your site is grey, it is giving the appearance of a line where as it is actually background colour coming through the transparent PNG.

Comment: This resolved the issue. Apparently safari required an extra few pixels of overlap than Firefox and IE because it was rending the height slightly off.